# Import png into RStudio

Tags: r, image, png, rstudio

I wanna import a png image onto RStudio and visualize it in the Plots tab as it is a standard R graphical output. Any ideas?

Tnx

Dag

Comment: What have you already tried? Where did you get stuck? _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you look at the png package and readPNG function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load and visualize image files in R you can use the `readImage()` and `display()` functions from [EBImage](http://bioconductor.org/packages/EBImage/):

```
library(EBImage)

img = readImage("path/to/your/image/file or URL")
display(img, method = "raster")
```

Cheers,

Andrzej